# Angular: Find max date

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to find and display the maximum date in a data set. Some example data would be 21/05/2021, 01/04/2021, 15/05/2021, and the result should be 21/05/21. I'm trying to write a function, but it's not working. When I use `console.log` to show the result, it is set to 0. I don't know what that `this.maxDueDate` must be equal to.

**app.ts:**

```
checkDueDate() {
  this.maxDueDate = 0
  if (this.depositTasks.length !== undefined) {
    for (let i = 0; this.depositTasks.length > i; i++) {
      if (this.maxDueDate < this.depositTasks[i].dueDate) {
        this.maxDueDate = this.depositTasks[i].dueDate
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the max date directly by doing a sort.

```
this.maxDueDate = this.depositTasks.sort((a,b) => 
  new Date(b.dueDate).getTime() - new Date(a.dueDate).getTime())[0].dueDate;
```

The sort function returns an array with the depositTask objects sorted according to their dates in descending order. So, the first element of the array will be the one with the maxium date value.

Comment: thank you it's work!! but Do you have a shorter way?

Comment: This is the short, single-line solution that I could think of (to get the maxDueDate exactly as you want it).

Comment: thank you for your answer It's work as I want it but code so long I don't little understand.

Comment: Refer to the Array.sort() function to understand how the sorting works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: thank you. Can I ask you? what's this 'dueDate'. You set it up yourself, right?

Comment: You have mentioned "this.depositTasks[i].dueDate". So, I assumed there's a dueDate property in the depositTask object. The sorting is done on the basis of the value of that property.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your dates to milliseconds
new Date(d1).getTime()
and now you can compare or can find the max from the array. Math.max() is one way but there are many.

```
let arr=['03/21/2021', '01/04/2021', '05/15/2021']
let data = arr.map(date=> new Date(date).getTime())
console.log(data)
let max = Math.max(...data)
console.log(new Date(max))
```